# How should my MANIFEST.MF look?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I have the following directly structure:

```
mp1
├── lib
│   └── kryonet-2.21-all.jar
├── mp1.iml
├── out
│   ├── artifacts
│   │   └── UX
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │       └── UX.jar
├── src
│   ├── [.class files]
│   └── cs425
│       └── mp1
│           ├── agent
│           │   ├── [handlers].java
│           ├── common
│           │   ├── [commons].java
│           ├── main
│           │   └── UX.java
│           └── network
│               ├── [networks].java
```

I'm completely new to mainfest files, and am just trying to get a `.jar` to run on a remote box. My manifest looks like this right now:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: cs425.mp1.main.UX

But I just keep getting,

```
~/mp1$ java -jar UX.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile UX.jar
```

Any help? I'm not sure what options to add for my external library and how to define my classpath.

Comment: Is there an empty newline at the end of the manifest? I don't know if this is still a problem in newer Java versions, but older versions required an empty line.

Comment: Yeah, there is - I got an error about it in my IDE at first

Comment: What do you mean, `src` contains `[.class files]`? The `.class` files should be next to the `.java` files (not recommended), or in a similar directory structure under a different folder, e.g. `bin` or `out`. --- I also hope the other `.java` files aren't truely named with [brackets] in the name.

Comment: If the class files are all in the `src` folder, then you forgot to specify the `package` statement at the beginning of each `.java` file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the only thing I was missing was the classpath to my external `.jar` file. My manifest now looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: cs425.mp1.main.UX
Class-Path: kryonet-2.21-all.jar
```

After making sure all of my required files are part of the artifact package (my manifest file, external jar, etc), the issue seems to have gone away.